# Obtain version of packages installed from docker image/container

Tags: python, docker, pip, package, dockerfile

Assume I pull a docker image using `docker pull image1`. The image is for a python application and its dependencies. I can run a container from this image, and everything works well. I am interested in finding the list of all installed packages and their dependencies from the running container or pulled image. I am wondering if there is a way to get that.

Note: I know if there is a requirements.txt, then I can find all the information but assume there is no such thing.

Comment: Run `pip freeze` inside the container

Comment: Something like `docker run -it pip freeze >requirements.txt`